# Unable to update using apt. (the old "packages have been kept back" issue)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, pop-os

Can't update PopOS 21.04. I've already tried removing all manually added ppa and removing manually installed apps I can think of.

What the heck is going on here? Tried all this...

> └─$ apt update
>
> Hit:1 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary groovy
> InRelease Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
> Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease
> Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease
> Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
> Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
> Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu groovy InRelease
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done 25 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list
> --upgradable' to see them.

Ok cool..

> └─$ apt upgrade
>
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done The
> following packages have been kept back:   apt apt-utils fwupd-signed
> libapt-pkg6.0 libegl-mesa0 libgbm1 libglapi-mesa   libglapi-mesa:i386
> libglx-mesa0 libglx-mesa0:i386 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to
> remove and 10 not upgraded.

Okay you clown...
Another:

> └─$ sudo aptitude upgrade
>
> Resolving dependencies...                 No
> packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed. 0 packages upgraded,
> 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded. Need to get 0 B of
> archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

Ok screw it!!
Another:

> └─$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
>
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done
> Calculating upgrade... Done The following packages have been kept
> back:   apt apt-utils fwupd-signed libapt-pkg6.0 libegl-mesa0 libgbm1
> libglapi-mesa   libglapi-mesa:i386 libglx-mesa0 libglx-mesa0:i386 0
> upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.

Ugh.
Another:

> └─$ apt install apt apt-utils fwupd-signed libapt-pkg6.0 libegl-mesa0
> libgbm1 libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libglx-mesa0
> libglx-mesa0:i386
>
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency
> tree        Reading state information... Done Some packages could not
> be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible
> situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some
> required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of
> Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  apt : Depends:
> adduser but it is not going to be installed
> Recommends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed  dictionaries-common : Depends: debconf (>= 1.5.5) but it is not going
> to be installed or
> debconf-2.0
> Depends: libtext-iconv-perl but it is not going to be installed  fwupd : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.63.0) but it
> is not going to be installed
> Depends: libfwupd2 (>= 1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1~1627329462~21.04~3e64f3f) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: libfwupdplugin1 (>= 1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1~1627329462~21.04~3e64f3f) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.67.3) but 2.66.1-2ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
> Depends: libgusb2 (>= 0.3.5) but 0.3.4-0.2 is to be installed
> Depends: libjcat1 (>= 0.1.3) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not installable
> Recommends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
> Recommends: dbus
> Recommends: secureboot-db but it is not going to be installed
> Recommends: udisks2  libglx-mesa0 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri but it is not going to be installed  libglx-mesa0:i386 : Depends:
> libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
> libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 : Depends: libkrb5-3:i386 (= 1.17-10ubuntu0.1)
> but it is not going to be installed E: Error,
> pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by
> held packages.

Is there a way to fix this without hosing the entire install? I haven't even installed that much or been using it very heavily, it's a fairly new laptop - a little disappointing but I'd rather try fighting this one out a little more than re-install anything.

Edit for requested info (sorry I don't know why the font is huge):

> $ cat sources.list
>
> ## See sources.list(5) for more information, especialy
>
> ## Remember that you can only use http, ftp or file URIs
>
> ## CDROMs are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.
>
> ## deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 20.10 *Groovy Gorilla* - Release amd64 (20210510)]/ groovy main restricted
>
> ## deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 20.10 *Groovy Gorilla* - Release amd64 (20210510)]/ stable main restricted
>
> ## deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 20.10 *Groovy Gorilla* - Release amd64 (20210510)]/ unstable main restricted

Commented out but there are 4 files inside the directory:

> $ cat pop-os-apps.sources  X-Repolib-Name: Pop_OS Applications
> Enabled: yes Types: deb URIs: http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary
> Suites: groovy Components: main

> $ cat system.sources  X-Repolib-Name: Pop_OS System Sources Enabled:
> yes Types: deb deb-src URIs: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
> Suites: groovy groovy-security groovy-updates groovy-backports
> Components: main restricted universe multiverse
> X-Repolib-Default-Mirror: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

> $ cat system76-ubuntu-pop-groovy.list  deb
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu/ groovy main deb-src
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu/ groovy main

> $ cat pop-os-ppa.list
>
> ### This file was generated by pop-upgrade
>
> ### X-Repolib-Name: Pop_OS PPA deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu hirsute main deb-src
>
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu hirsute main

Edit #2:
I commented out all 'groovy' references. For the pop-os-apps.sources and system.sources, I replaced them with identical lines but with 'hirsute' instead. Still looks scary:

> └─$ apt update Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute
> InRelease [269 kB] Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu
> hirsute InRelease                                 Get:3
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease [110
> kB]                        Get:4 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary
> hirsute InRelease [8,441 B] Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> hirsute-updates InRelease [115 kB] Get:6
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease [101
> kB] Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main Sources
> [1,316 kB] Get:8 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary hirsute/main all
> Packages [608 B] Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> hirsute/restricted Sources [16.8 kB] Get:10
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe Sources [17.0 MB]
> Get:11 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary hirsute/main amd64 Packages
> [4,600 B]   Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> hirsute/multiverse Sources [285 kB]               Get:13
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages [1,394
> kB] Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main i386
> Packages [1,025 kB] Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> hirsute/main Translation-en [511 kB] Get:16
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
> [469 kB] Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main
> DEP-11 48x48 Icons [102 kB] Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> hirsute/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [157 kB] Get:19
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
> [15.8 kB] Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main
> DEP-11 128x128 Icons [345 kB] Get:21
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
> [29.5 kB] Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> hirsute/restricted i386 Packages [20.3 kB] Get:23
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted amd64 Packages
> [78.0 kB] Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> hirsute/restricted Translation-en [12.0 kB] Get:25
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted amd64 c-n-f
> Metadata [436 B] Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> hirsute/universe amd64 Packages [13.2 MB] Get:27
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe i386 Packages
> [7,087 kB] Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe
> Translation-en [5,441 kB] Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> hirsute/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,848 kB] Get:30
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe DEP-11 48x48
> Icons [3,338 kB] Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> hirsute/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [8,115 kB] Get:32
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe DEP-11 64x64@2
> Icons [57.1 kB] Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> hirsute/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons [14.6 MB] Get:34
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 c-n-f
> Metadata [279 kB]
> Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse amd64
> Packages [206 kB]
> Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse i386
> Packages [109 kB]
> Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse
> Translation-en [108 kB]
> Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse amd64
> DEP-11 Metadata [47.3 kB]
> Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse DEP-11
> 48x48 Icons [29.6 kB]
> Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse DEP-11
> 64x64 Icons [198 kB]
> Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse DEP-11
> 64x64@2 Icons [214 B]
> Get:42 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse DEP-11
> 128x128 Icons [307 kB]
> Get:43 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse amd64
> c-n-f Metadata [8,124 B]
> Get:44 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted
> Sources [14.3 kB]
> Get:45 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe
> Sources [20.1 kB]
> Get:46 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main
> Sources [85.6 kB]
> Get:47 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/multiverse
> Sources [3,280 B]
> Get:48 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main amd64
> Packages [293 kB]
> Get:49 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main i386
> Packages [116 kB]
> Get:50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main
> Translation-en [73.7 kB]
> Get:51 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main amd64
> DEP-11 Metadata [9,672 B]
> Get:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main
> DEP-11 48x48 Icons [7,781 B]
> Get:53 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main
> DEP-11 64x64 Icons [19.5 kB]
> Get:54 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main
> DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]
> Get:55 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main
> DEP-11 128x128 Icons [32.9 kB]
> Get:56 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main amd64
> c-n-f Metadata [4,696 B]
> Get:57 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted
> amd64 Packages [233 kB]
> Get:58 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted
> i386 Packages [22.0 kB]
> Get:59 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted
> Translation-en [32.5 kB]
> Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted
> amd64 c-n-f Metadata [508 B]
> Get:61 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe
> amd64 Packages [227 kB]
> Get:62 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe
> i386 Packages [195 kB]
> Get:63 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe
> Translation-en [48.6 kB]
> Get:64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe
> amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,668 B]
> Get:65 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe
> DEP-11 48x48 Icons [7,654 B]
> Get:66 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe
> DEP-11 64x64 Icons [9,140 B]
> Get:67 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe
> DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]
> Get:68 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe
> DEP-11 128x128 Icons [7,417 B]
> Get:69 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe
> amd64 c-n-f Metadata [5,572 B]
> Get:70 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/multiverse
> i386 Packages [1,704 B]
> Get:71 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/multiverse
> amd64 Packages [3,372 B]
> Get:72 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/multiverse
> Translation-en [828 B]
> Get:73 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/multiverse
> amd64 c-n-f Metadata [220 B]
> Get:74 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/multiverse
> Sources [8,384 B]
> Get:75 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted
> Sources [14.2 kB]
> Get:76 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main
> Sources [154 kB]
> Get:77 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe
> Sources [49.1 kB]
> Get:78 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main i386
> Packages [210 kB]
> Get:79 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64
> Packages [427 kB]
> Get:80 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main
> Translation-en [111 kB]
> Get:81 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64
> DEP-11 Metadata [97.9 kB]
> Get:82 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main DEP-11
> 48x48 Icons [27.0 kB]
> Get:83 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main DEP-11
> 64x64 Icons [53.4 kB]
> Get:84 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main DEP-11
> 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]
> Get:85 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main DEP-11
> 128x128 Icons [114 kB]
> Get:86 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64
> c-n-f Metadata [7,892 B]
> Get:87 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted
> amd64 Packages [235 kB]
> Get:88 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted
> i386 Packages [22.0 kB]
> Get:89 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted
> Translation-en [32.8 kB]
> Get:90 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted
> amd64 c-n-f Metadata [504 B]
> Get:91 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe
> amd64 Packages [343 kB]
> Get:92 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe
> i386 Packages [244 kB]
> Get:93 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe
> Translation-en [85.2 kB]
> Get:94 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe
> amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [57.7 kB]
> Get:95 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe
> DEP-11 48x48 Icons [25.4 kB]
> Get:96 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe
> DEP-11 64x64 Icons [40.4 kB]
> Get:97 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe
> DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]
> Get:98 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe
> DEP-11 128x128 Icons [81.0 kB]
> Get:99 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe
> amd64 c-n-f Metadata [7,848 B]
> Get:100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/multiverse
> i386 Packages [2,384 B]
> Get:101 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/multiverse
> amd64 Packages [7,356 B]
> Get:102 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/multiverse
> Translation-en [2,196 B]
> Get:103 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/multiverse
> amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
> Get:104 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/multiverse
> DEP-11 48x48 Icons [1,865 B]
> Get:105 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/multiverse
> DEP-11 64x64 Icons [2,498 B]
> Get:106 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/multiverse
> DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]
> Get:107 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/multiverse
> DEP-11 128x128 Icons [29 B]
> Get:108 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/multiverse
> amd64 c-n-f Metadata [440 B]
> Get:109 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports/universe
> Sources [2,516 B]
> Get:110 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports/main
> amd64 c-n-f Metadata [112 B]
> Get:111 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> hirsute-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [120 B]
> Get:112 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports/universe
> i386 Packages [2,608 B]
> Get:113 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports/universe
> amd64 Packages [3,708 B]
> Get:114 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports/universe
> Translation-en [1,252 B]
> Get:115 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports/universe
> amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [9,348 B]
> Get:116 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports/universe
> DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]
> Get:117 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports/universe
> DEP-11 64x64 Icons [1,788 B]
> Get:118 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports/universe
> DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]
> Get:119 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports/universe
> DEP-11 128x128 Icons [29 B]
> Get:120 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports/universe
> amd64 c-n-f Metadata [176 B]
> Get:121 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> hirsute-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [120 B]
> Fetched 84.3 MB in 8s (11.1 MB/s)
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done 1255 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list
> --upgradable' to see them.

apt upgrade shows huge changes ending with this:

> The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:   gnome-control-center
> gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center-faces 1246 upgraded, 57
> newly installed, 3 downgraded, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded. Need to
> get 1,067 MB/1,084 MB of archives. After this operation, 514 MB of
> additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n

Edit 3:
After reversing course back to groovy and removing hirsute, this looks better (I think)?

> └─$ apt upgrade Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done The
> following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
> required:   gnome-shell-extension-cosmic-dock libpugixml1v5
> libqalculate21 libqalculate21-data pop-cosmic pop-launcher qalc
> touchegg yaru-theme-gnome-shell Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove
> them. The following NEW packages will be installed:
> gnome-shell-extension-alt-tab-raise-first-window
> gnome-shell-extension-always-show-workspaces
> gnome-shell-extension-pop-shop-details linux-headers-5.11.0-7620
> linux-headers-5.11.0-7620-generic linux-image-5.11.0-7620-generic
> linux-modules-5.11.0-7620-generic
> linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-7620-generic python3-distro-info
> python3-distupgrade   python3-update-manager The following packages
> will be upgraded:   debconf debconf-i18n ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
> update-manager-core The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
> accountsservice amd-ppt-bin appstream-data-pop
> appstream-data-pop-icons com.github.donadigo.eddy
> firmware-manager-notify firmware-manager-shared gdm3
> gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0   gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-7
> gnome-online-accounts gnome-settings-daemon
> gnome-settings-daemon-common gnome-shell gnome-shell-common
> gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng   gnome-shell-extension-prefs
> gnome-shell-extension-system76-power gnome-terminal
> gnome-terminal-data hidpi-daemon kernelstub libaccountsservice0
> libegl-mesa0 libfirmware-manager libfwupd2   libgbm1 libgdm1
> libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386
> libglx-mesa0 libglx-mesa0:i386 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common
> libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libmutter-7-0   libnss-systemd libnvidia-cfg1-470
> libnvidia-common-470 libnvidia-compute-470 libnvidia-compute-470:i386
> libnvidia-decode-470 libnvidia-decode-470:i386 libnvidia-encode-470
> libnvidia-encode-470:i386 libnvidia-extra-470 libnvidia-fbc1-470
> libnvidia-fbc1-470:i386 libnvidia-gl-470 libnvidia-gl-470:i386
> libnvidia-ifr1-470 libnvidia-ifr1-470:i386 libpam-systemd
> libpop-desktop-widget libpop-theme-switcher libpop-upgrade-gtk
> libs76-hidpi-widget libsystemd0 libudev1 libxatracker2 linux-firmware
> linux-generic linux-headers-generic   linux-image-generic
> linux-libc-dev linux-system76 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers
> mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 mutter-common
> nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal
> network-manager-config-connectivity-pop nvidia-compute-utils-470
> nvidia-dkms-470 nvidia-driver-460 nvidia-driver-470
> nvidia-kernel-common-470 nvidia-kernel-source-470 nvidia-utils-470
> plymouth-theme-pop-basic pop-default-settings pop-desktop pop-fonts
> pop-gnome-initial-setup pop-gnome-shell-theme pop-gtk-theme
> pop-icon-theme pop-session pop-shell   pop-shell-plugin-system76-power
> pop-shell-shortcuts pop-shop pop-sound-theme pop-theme pop-transition
> pop-upgrade pop-wallpapers popsicle popsicle-gtk python3-repolib
> repoman   sessioninstaller system76-acpi-dkms system76-dkms
> system76-driver system76-firmware-daemon system76-io-dkms
> system76-oled system76-power system76-wallpapers systemd systemd-sysv
> systemd-timesyncd ubuntu-drivers-common udev
> xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470 4 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 120
> downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need to get 737 MB/738 MB
> of archives. After this operation, 330 MB of additional disk space
> will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `hirsute` from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or the files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Oh! So somehow I have conflicting repos in there? But wouldn't I want to remove Groovy since hirsute matches my PopOS version and groovy is older? A list I found says: 21.10  impish, 21.04  hirsute, 20.10  groovy, 20.04  focal

Comment: Oh, I just noticed all the rest say groovy too so I guess your suggestion is probably right. Will give this a try. (Unfortunately this is a different PC so I can't paste sources.list here.)

Comment: sources.list only has 'groovy' stuff in it, although it's all commented out

Comment: Ok I managed to get the contents of sources.list and the files inside sources.list.d directory as an edit. Switching to hirsute seems like I'd be removing a lot of stuff though, do I need to just comment out all the groovy stuff?

Comment: Okay I added a second edit with the result after changing all groovy to hirsute. It's a huge looking update, I'm not sure if it looks correct.

Comment: @Manius From the `sources.list` your distribution is `20.04` not `21.04`. `groovy` is the right codename for your distribution.

Comment: Okay hopefully the last edit (Q is at the max length!). Reversing course to groovy for everything, apt update only says 4 updates. One final edit for the apt upgrade output... there are some downgrades but I think it looks okay? I guess I need to downgrade the later codename stuff that got in there after the failed pop upgrade...

Comment: @Manius Yes you need to downgrade because some packages come from `hirsute` and need to be downgraded to groovy.

Comment: Pulled the trigger on the last. It looked good almost to completion, but of course now I'm getting some "temporary failure resolving 'apt.pop-os.org'.. hoping it's just some temp server issue. I think at least I'm pointed in the right direction now, anyway. I had no idea this type of situation of conflicting repos could even happen without some more obvious alert. It must have been a failed upgrade from a while ago. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, we did it! Successful reboot after all updates done. Now I do get the "support ended for this release" message again, but I'll leave the system upgrade for another day. Thanks again.