# "The following packages have been kept back", a new twist on an old puzzle

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt-get, aptitude

Very much what the title says. The new twist is that I am aware of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it) and of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1107334/apt-says-packages-have-been-kept-back-what-to-do) and of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1688512/unable-to-update-using-apt-the-old-packages-have-been-kept-back-issue)  discussions, and relative replies. But...

```
  me@me:~$ sudo apt-get update
        Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                    
        Hit:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                           
        Hit:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease        
        Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
        Reading package lists... Done
  me@me:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
        Reading package lists... Done
        Building dependency tree... Done 
        Reading state information... Done
        Calculating upgrade... Done
        The following packages have been kept back:
           tzdata xdg-utils
        0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

In other words, I do not have conflicting package repos, as suggested in ref. [3](https://superuser.com/questions/1688512/unable-to-update-using-apt-the-old-packages-have-been-kept-back-issue), and I have used *apt-get dist-upgrade*, as suggested in the first two references. Of course
I **can** update manually,

```
  me@me:~$ sudo apt-get install -y tzdata xdg-utils
        Reading package lists... Done
        Building dependency tree... Done
        Reading state information... Done
        The following packages will be upgraded:
           tzdata xdg-utils
        2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
        Need to get 397 kB of archives.
        After this operation, 48,1 kB disk space will be freed.
        Get:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 tzdata all 2022c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0 [335 kB]
        Get:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 xdg-utils all 1.1.3-4.1ubuntu3~22.04.1 [61,9 kB]
        Fetched 397 kB in 0s (1.462 kB/s)    
        Preconfiguring packages ...
        (Reading database ... 346424 files and directories currently installed.                
        Preparing to unpack .../tzdata_2022c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0_all.deb ...
        Unpacking tzdata (2022c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0) over (2022a-0ubuntu1) ..              
        Preparing to unpack .../xdg-utils_1.1.3-4.1ubuntu3~22.04.1_all.deb ...
        Unpacking xdg-utils (1.1.3-4.1ubuntu3~22.04.1) over (1.1.3-4.1ubuntu1.22.04.1) ...
        Setting up tzdata (2022c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0) ...

        Current default time zone: 'Europe/Paris'
        Universal Time is now:  Fri Sep  2 07:52:12 UTC 2022.
        Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

        Setting up xdg-utils (1.1.3-4.1ubuntu3~22.04.1) ...
        Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
```

Thus this is a nuisance more than a problem, but: first, it happens rather often, despite my attempts at clearing caches, and so on (*apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean*), and second I would like to know what causes the problem, because the fact that the update does not take place even after an *apt-get dist-upgrade* clearly makes me suspect there might be more than meets the eye. Cheers, and thanks.

Comment: If these are [Phased Updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-that-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-as-automat/1421130#1421130), then by forcing the installation you became a beta-tester.

Comment: @harrymc yes!!! This is it! If you write it as an answer I will accept your answer. And thanks, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these are
[Phased Updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-that-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-as-automat/1421130#1421130),
then by forcing the installation you became a beta-tester.

Such packages have limited distribution, intended for some users to get
first in order to report a broken package.
It's possible, but not advised, to force the installation of these packages.

To test if a held back package is phased, run
`apt-cache policy <packagename>`
and look for the 'phased' percentage, that looks like "(phased xx%)".